# photosynth is not detecting my previous photos

Tags: photos

There is an app called PHOTOSYNTH,by which we can take 360degree panaroma photos.I capture some photos using this app.Those captures photos were in SD Card.Now due to some problems I needed to reset my phone.So after resetting my phone,Photosynth app is not detecting any previous photos.Now I can't do anything with those photos.
So how to make that app to detect those photos?

Comment: Try uninstalling the app and install it again and check..

Comment: @vembutech I have tried that,nothing good came out of that.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just reset my phone and tried this. As far as I can tell, there is no way to load your previous images. I think storing your panoramas on photosynth.net (an option in the app) could perhaps prevent this from happening in the future.